# Is it possible to build a React-Native app for Windows in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, react-native

Last Thursday I was asked to code fairly small app for an Android device and I went with React-Native. The app is now in the testing phase (it's really small) and I was asked again if we could also deploy the app on a Windows machine.

I code exclusively in Linux, but I also know about [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) which does produce an output for both Linux, Mac and Windows regardless of the environment, so I said : "Sure! I'll see what I can do!"

But reading the [`react-native-windows`](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows#getting-started)' documentation, I'm not sure if that's possible. At least it is not clear to me.

So the question is not really "can it be done?" but rather "how can it be done?" I could request a Windows machine if I *have* to, but if I can avoid it I'd rather not go there because that would mean maintaining two computers where one'd be used *only* for that purpose, etc.

**Edit** : Basically, I am wondering if it is possible to generate an executable JAR archive of a React-Native project which then can be launched from any Java-supported desktop computer.